# What does the warning FABRIC_E_CONNECTION_CLOSED_BY_REMOTE_END mean?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

On my service fabric cluster in azure, each machine has warnings generated about dropping messages.

For example:

```
dropping message {1bd9a9c6-b922-48fa-9a8e-d563804c600a}:153759, Actor = Transport, Action = '', fault = FABRIC_E_CONNECTION_CLOSED_BY_REMOTE_END
```

As far as I can tell nothing is wrong, but I'm trying to make sure that there are no problems.

Comment: I think we know what is happening, connection was closed by remote end. **Why?** I would like to know too. Here is [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.fabric.fabricerrorcode.aspx). If you scroll you'll find this explanation: `FabricConnectionClosedByRemoteEnd` - "A FabricErrorCode that indicates the connection was closed by the remote end." God help us with such great insight.